# .htaccess that rewrites only if conditions are met

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I am working on an Angular 4 project for my work. The one thing I have 0 experience in is the .htaccess file.

Because we are using Angular, we are have the following rewrite conditions:

```
## Normal Rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

However, I would like to have a redirect to maintenance.html if we are under maintenance.

I have found the following code for that:

```
## Maintenance rewrite
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
Maintenance: true

If maintenance === true {

// Execute maintenance rewrite

} else

// Execute normal rewrite
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may set environment variable and use like `RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} = maintenance`,

Comment: How dose/should the web server know if your are in maintenance mode or not?